Can you identify this theme music?
I just encountered a background music in this video:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Unexpected/s/aSlB9DXbqJ
I have a hunch that I have heard it before, in a superhero animated TV show intro. I checked the Batman and X-Men animated series intros without luck.

That's the "Black Suit Theme" composed by Christopher Young for Spider-Man 3 (2007).



You can listen to several different versions of it here.

I'm frankly disappointed that it took you eight whole minutes to solve this one. Turn in your badge and your gun on the way out.

Ouch. Tough crowd...
